# Agora voice is not coming when notification arrives

Tags: agora.io

while running live audio session inside my app, a notification arrives of any other app, at that time sounds get disappear, sound does not reconnect automatically,

we need to left channel and join the channel again. is there any way we can reconnect audio after interruption?

Answer (score 0):

Which SDK are you using? What channel profile have you defined? Also, it would be great if you could share your SDK logs to better understand this problem. You can share it on the Agora community slack channel: http://agora.io/en/join-slack/